# Providing a field accessor method as an argument

Tags: java

G'day comrades. I have a problem.

I have two methods which are completely duplicate apart from that they are accessing a different field. I cannot pass the field value as a parameter because accessing takes place inside a loop (simplified example):

```
   public final class Thing {

        ImmutableList<Box> boxes;

        public int getNumberOfApples() {
            int total = 0;
            for (Box box : boxes) {
                total += box.getApplesCount();
            }
            return total;
        }

        public int getNumberOfPears() {
            int total = 0;
            for (Box box : boxes) {
                total += box.getPearsCount();
            }
            return total;
        }
    }
```

I could put my fruit into a map and passed the field name as a parameter but it looks dirty and I am quite happy with the current class composition. So the question is - how do I refactor my code to have a single method of type:

```
public int getNumberOfFruit(SomethingMagic) {
    moreMagic;
    return total;
}
```

Cheerio.

Comment: switch condition or if condition...pass a string namely "apple" or "pears" to your function and make it general - getNumberOfFruit(String fruitName).. if(type.equals("apple")) doSomething ... if(type.equals("pears")) doSomethingElse..

Comment: Thought of that as well but that still looks ugly. What if I get one hundred fruit types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you could have something like:

```
public interface Function<In, Out> {
    Out apply(In input);
}
```

Then:

```
public int getCount(Function<Box, Integer> projection) {
    int total = 0;
    for (Box box : boxes) {
        total += projection(box);
    }
    return total;
}
```

For the moment constructing that projection will be ugly, e.g.

```
int pears = thing.getCount(new Function<Box, Integer>() {
    @Override public Integer apply(Box input) {
        return box.getPearsCount();
    }
});
```

but in Java 8, it'll be much simpler with lambda expressions:

```
int pears = thing.getCount(box -> box.getPearsCount());
```

Note that Raffaele Rossi's answer is slightly more specific than mine by making the interface non-generic. This means it can be more efficient, as there's no need to box the counts - but less reusable, of course. Which approach you decide to use is a judgement call which will largely depend on your actual use case.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks Jon!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a *functional* approach. Define a function to pass into your `getNumberOfFruit` which will retrieve the number of the correct fruit. Something like:

```
public interface FruitCounter {
    int apply(Box box);
}

public int getNumberOfFruit(FruitCounter counter) {
    int total = 0;
    for (Box box : boxes) {
        total += counter.apply(box);
     }
     return total;
}
```

Then pass the proper implementation to count apples or pears:

```
int numOfApples theThing.getNumberOfFruit(new FruitCounter() {
    @Override
    public int apply(Box box) {
        return box.getApplesCount();
    });

int numOfPears theThing.getNumberOfFruit(new FruitCounter() {
    @Override
    public int apply(Box box) {
        return box.getPearsCount();
    });
```